# Returning a Value from a .bat File to CFEXECUTE

Tags: batch-file, coldfusion, cpu-usage, cfexecute

I have a batch file with the following code to pull the current server CPU usage:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage /value ^|find "="') do set /a cpu=%%i
echo %cpu%
```

Using ColdFusion's CFEXECUTE, I would like to run this batch file and return the echoed value:

```
<cfexecute name="#PathToBatchFile#" variable="Usage">
<cfdump var="#Usage#">
```

Running the above results in ColdFusion 2021 saying "Usage" is undefined.

The batch file can output the value to a file using the "outputfile" attribute --

```
<cfexecute name="#PathToBatchFile#" outputfile="#OutputFile#">
```

-- then I can use CFFILE to read it, but that seems rather roundabout. Anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. @Mofi - I fully admit to not know much about writing batch files (or powershell for that matter). It was mostly a copy and paste situation. I tried powershell using the command "wmic cpu get loadpercentage" and it does indeed return the usage through the variable. Thank you! Going to leave the question open in case someone has a solution for returning from batch files as well.